# How to minify multiple/mixed file types

Tags: php, html, css, performance, minify

I do a lot of web performance optimization work, often on projects where (clearly) not every one is on the same page with development vs. production environments.

Most projects I work on use HTML, CSS and JS, but very frequently the HTML that concerns me is in PHP templates (mostly HTML).

Which PHP minifiers (if any) will work correctly on files which are primarily HTML and which JS and CSS minifiers will yield code which is developer-friendly but condensed (e.g. CSS files with each rule on one line while preserving comments but deleting whitespace).

Due to the ease of running different tasks, I'm currently using Grunt and most of the 'contrib' plugins for most of this but there doesn't seem to be much ground between simple concatenation and full concatenation and minification (i.e. all code on one line).

Are there any tools that offer a middle ground and/or can handle mixed files types (i.e. PHP files which contain mostly HTML or files with a `.htm(l)` file extensions which contain PHP)?

Comment: I don't see the problem with js/css files. You have the development files and the run Grunt to minify them, while keeping the original ones to do it again. You use the minified files in your application. Much like tools such as LESS work. You don't include the .less file but use the outputted css.

Comment: My main concern is readabilty. I'm usually working on production code (and I don't think they are using preprocessors) and totally minified code is difficult to navigate and missing things like breaks between files and extraneous semi-colons. While I like to use Uglify and generate source maps and I know how to use DevTools in conjunction with these techniques, I can't assume everyone does and so I'd like to find a middle-ground approach.

Comment: IMHO people that don't understand the link between `jQuery.js` and `jQuery.min.js` shouldn't be touching production code. Production code sent to the client shouldn't contain comments, debug symbols etc. You might have trouble finding a tool to do what you want. Minification isn't about readability, one has the source code for that. In the past I've experimented with "on demand" minification of js and css using PHP. Before the files where sent to the client they were minified by a PHP script. Maybe that might be a path worth pursuing?

Comment: I feel the same, unfortunately I'm more of a position now where I need to speed up the site without getting into making changes that might break things (I just started here and they don't seem to care about performance as much as I do). Thanks for the input, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most satisfactory solution I found (as of yesterday)...sorry but I have to mention a specific program (I assume other programs might do the same).

The clearest explanation I can give is with CSS:

Open the project in Sublime Text, do a 'Replace' with the Regular Expression matching option activated find `\n\n` (2 carriage returns) and replace with `\n` (1 carriage return).

Save.

Then open the project in an IDE, set the code formatting preferences so that the declarations, properties and closing brackets are on their own lines, and each is indented an equal amount.

I then applied those settings to the entire project and did a code reformatting. To prevent psuedo class matching I set it so that there is a space after the colons that separate rules from declarations. For example:

```
a:hover{
font-weight: bold;
}
p{
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Then I did a 'find all' for a `:` (followed immediately by a space—in Sublime Text I just highlighted a colon and the trailing space then chose the 'select all' option (command+control+g on a Mac).

I then moved the cursor(s) to the start of each line (command+◀︎ [that's a left arrow]) and deleted until all properties were on a single line.

I then moved down to the next line, the lines which only have a `}` (closing bracket) and deleted until it was on the same line as the properties and declarations.

I then adjusted this process to work on every file I needed (PHP/HTML, CSS, JS).

The end result is compact, human-friendly, readable, code that has all the developer-friendly features intact (semi-colons after the last property in a declaration, declarations on separate lines).